# Javascript does not stop running

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I´ve got the problem, that this little js does not stop to run... 
Or i say it better like, he stops, but does not exit.

```
function main(){
if(laenge<=1){
    alert("exit");
    return;}
var fs = require('fs');var i=0;
var all = fs.open('acc_all.txt', 'r');
var laenge = 25999;
while(!all.atEnd()){
    var line = all.readLine();
    console.log(line+" + "+laenge);
    i++;laenge--;
}
all.close();
}
main();
```

It looks like this ...
[Console screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txgfe.png)

Comment: when is `!all.atEnd()` true? That's the question :D!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add [`phantom.exit()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/method/exit.html) at the end of your main function.

You can set the `debug` flag to `true` to see additional information:

```
phantomjs --debug=true index.js
```

You might notice that when calling `phantom.exit()` it'll exit, but there is a 4 second delay. This is a known issue when there is an active network connection.

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14033